# how to use linecache.clearcache to clear the cache of a certain file?

Tags: python, caching

If I use linecache to read several files, and now the memory is to busy such that I want to clear a certain file cache rather than use 'linecache.clearcache()' to clear all the cache, what should I do?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same consideration as you.

So I wrote the test codes by myself. You can check it out.

https://ideone.com/xHxTEl

Basically using `linecache.clearcache()` which is out of for-loop could be much faster but it would consume much more RAM the same time. The RAM sacrifices for the speed. The speed could be **6 times faster** comparing to clearing cache every time in the for-loop!!!

In contrast, you can use `linecache.clearcache()` in your for-loop. It took less memory but slow...

For me, I would clear the cache out of the for-loop and use multi-threads to chunk files into blocks. Extend the RAM and SWAP to be ready for the fast speed.

Comment: What I really care about is how can I implement big data read and write on server. So linecache seems like ram-reliable too much... I think replacing it with distributed file system is a good idea maybe

Comment: You are welcome. Yes `linecache` relies on RAM mostly. I have been using it in a project called [`jsonpyes`](https://github.com/xros/jsonpyes). The first thing for processing big data with `linecache` is to make sure that your data would be chunked or cut into pieces. So it would take good use of computer hardware. Well, it depends on your demands.